# Why can't I see the Alt Text of the image when I inspect element?

Tags: html, alt, inspect-element

Below is my code in React.

```
var $img = $('<img>', {
src: src,
'data-asset-id': assetId,
draggable: false,
alt: 'Add image description',
title: 'Add image description'
});
```

This gets called when you upload an image. I hardcoded the alt text and title for the image, to test, as you can see above. But when I right click on the image and press 'inspect element', I see: [image: this]. It doesn't show me the alt text, or the title. So my question is, is the alt text being set properly, or what's wrong? Is there a better way to test if an image has alt text?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that some of the HTML attributes were getting stripped out while converting to CML. So all I had to change was the `alt: true` instead of `false` so that it doesn't get stripped out.